# Granting privileges for a user doesn't appear to apply even after flushing

Tags: mysql, permissions, sql

I'm working on creating a test system and need to grant a user remote database access. I'm doing this with the following:

```
mysql> SHOW GRANTS for codingo;
ERROR 1141 (42000): There is no such grant defined for user 'codingo' on host '%'
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* to 'codingo'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

However after I `flush privileges` and then review them, they don't appear to apply:

```
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW GRANTS for codingo;
ERROR 1141 (42000): There is no such grant defined for user 'codingo' on host '%'
```

I'm currently using:

> mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.23, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine
>   wrapper

The user is however showing with permissions when I perform:

```
mysql> select * from mysql.user where user='codingo' and host='localhost';
```

I've also edited:

```
/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
```

To bind-address `0.0.0.0` (planning to harden after debugging this) which still hasn't allowed remote connections.

However I'm unable to connect to this remotely, or even locally with this user.

This is on a fully patched Ubuntu server. I've also run the MySQL hardening script, so I presume something there is preventing me from creating an additional administrator, but I don't know enough about this to solve the problem via Google. Certainly open to suggestions!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error says it all

```
ERROR 1141 (42000): There is no such grant defined for user 'codingo' on host '%'
```

You set a grant for `localhost` but checked the grant for `%`.

Try

```
SHOW GRANTS for codingo@localhost;
```

Comment: Ah! Today I learnt. Since this then wasn't the cause and I could see the grants I decided to step back and create a new password for the user which in turn worked to solve my problem. Thank-you!